# Java Streams v .Net (C#) LINQ

Tags: java, c#-4.0

I need to know if a String or char array has duplicate characters and if so how many of each duplicates there are.

With LINQ I can do it the following way:-

```
class Program {
    private const string SOURCE = "appearances";

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var testQ =
            from ch in SOURCE
            group ch by ch into testG
            where testG.Count<char>() > 1
            select testG;

        int num;
        foreach (var tg in testQ) {
            num = tg.Count();
            Console.Out.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", tg.ElementAt(0), num);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest how I might go about it with Java streams?

Comment: Sort the characters in the string, and count the occurrences of each.

Answer (score 2):

You say `Stream` - I suppose you mean Java 8.

Here is how you would do it:

```
public Map<Character, Integer> countOccurs(final char[] input) {
    return countOccurs(new String(input));
}

public Map<Character, Integer> countOccurs(final String input) {
    return input.chars().
            collect(
                    HashMap::new,
                    (m, c) -> m.merge((char) c, 1, Integer::sum),
                    HashMap::putAll
            );
}
```

The idea is that we take an `IntStream` of the `char` values in the `String` as `int`. Then we `collect()` this `IntStream` to a `Map`; this is like a `foldLeft` operation from a functional language. The `Map.merge` method takes a key and a value and a lambda that merges an existing value and the new value if one is already in the `Map` - we pass `Integer::sum` to add the two values together.

The gymnastics with the `int` and `char` and `Character` is a legacy Java issue. There is no primitive `CharStream` in the new Java 8 API so we have to use an `IntStream` - we then have to cast the `int` to a `char` and then it will be autoboxed to a `Character`.

Example usage:

```
System.out.println(countOccurs("abbccddde"));
```

Output:

```
{a=1, b=2, c=2, d=3, e=1}
```

If you then want to filter the counts you can simply do:

```
final Map<Character, Integer> count = countOccurs("abbccddde");
count.entrySet().stream().
    filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1).
    forEach(System.out::println);
```

Which will give you:

```
b=2
c=2
d=3
```

If you want something similar in logic to your LINQ example, then this *would* work:

```
public Collection<? extends Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> countOccurs(final String input) {
    return input.chars().boxed().
            collect(groupingBy(identity())).entrySet().stream().
            filter(e -> e.getValue().size() > 1).
            map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>((char)(int)e.getKey(), e.getValue().size())).
            collect(toList());
}
```

But it's really quite ugly and requires an intermediate collection.

P.S. excuse the formatting, I'm not yet sure how to format long lines of `Stream` manipulation. I'm sure there'll be style guidelines established soon.

Comment: This is a bit late, but the standard is newline, indent, then .call(). This is how it's always been for chained method calls. Basically, your periods go down to the next line. :)